# Page jumps to bottom after making a Selection

Tags: javascript, woocommerce, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 for my woocommerce page, which worked pretty good so far. The problem that I have is that only in Safari (MacBook, iMac) the page starts to jump to the bottom, after someone makes a selection from the dropdown field. I didn't made any changes on the JavaScript code, so it's the original Select2. Is this a Safari Bug or Select2.

I uploaded a demo product to see the problem

https://www.amaoni.de/shop/unkategorisiert/test/

also I created a gif on giphy of the problem, to see it in action.

https://gph.is/g/GaX1wDZ

```
<span class="selection">
    <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-test-container">
        <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-test-container" title="test">test</span>
    <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span>
</span>
```

Comment: It doesn't do it on my machine: Google Chrome 72.0.3626.96, Windows 10 Pro. Also not on Firefox 65.0.1

Comment: This usually happen when there is `<a href="#xxx">` but in this case there are no `a` tag. I've also tested in Chromium 70 Fedora 29 and it works fine.

Comment: Yeah, i know. As descripted it only happens in Safari and only on iMacs and Macbooks

Comment: Yes I can confirm, I've used browserstack it jumps. You have lot of scripts. For start I would remove everything execept the select2 and check if it jumps and start adding files. When you add a file and it start jumping again you can use debugger to find scrollTop change in that file that was added last.

Comment: The other thing you can test is to change the theme, tonda includes ScrollToPlugin.min.js that may be causing this. If this is the case, and it don't jumps when you change the theme then you need to report to the theme author.

Comment: I tried this also, that but it didn't worked

Comment: Did you tried to remove file by file? Try to save whole page into a file, (at least on Chrome you can save file including all externals) then you can start deleting files and check if select still jumps. (last files should be your custom js file, select2 and jquery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating jQuery.

We experienced this same issue with being dropped to the bottom of the page after a selection (only in Safari) even on the latest version of select2 (4.1). Updating jQuery from version 3.3.1 to 3.6.1 immediately corrected it in our case.